# Spring Cloud Maven dependency conflict "NoSuchMethodError"

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gson, spring-data, spring-cloud

I'm currently working on Spring Cloud and Spring Data, but I got an error when I'm trying to run my program

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-05-19 10:20:35.886 ERROR 55581 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'alpsController' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/mht/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.3.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/hibox_microService/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/alps/AlpsController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(Lorg/springframework/data/rest/core/mapping/RepositoryDetectionStrategy;)Lorg/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(Lorg/springframework/data/rest/core/mapping/RepositoryDetectionStrategy;)Lorg/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(Lorg/springframework/data/rest/core/mapping/RepositoryDetectionStrategy;)Lorg/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(Lorg/springframework/data/rest/core/mapping/RepositoryDetectionStrategy;)Lorg/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration;
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestProperties.applyTo(RepositoryRestProperties.java:199) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.SpringBootRepositoryRestConfigurer.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(SpringBootRepositoryRestConfigurer.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerDelegate.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfigurerDelegate.java:60) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.config(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java:269) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$37cc9db.CGLIB$config$5(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$37cc9db$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7f866db5.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$37cc9db.config(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
... 42 common frames omitted
```

the root Exception is

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy`

I guess it's a Maven dependency conflict problem, but I use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and found no dependency conflict

My pom.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.vd.vf</groupId>
  <artifactId>hx_microService</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>hi_microService</name>
  <description>hi_microService using Spring Boot</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> 
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      </dependency> 

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

The problem first occurs when I add the `spring-cloud-starter-eureka` dependency to `pom.xml` so I guess it's cause by it. I also suspect the `gson` dependency has something to do with it, but still no clue.

Thanks in advance for reading this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR:

*Try to force a new version of Spring Data Rest. Preferably by upgrading the top level dependencies already in your `pom.xml`*

##Details, hopefully, helpful to debug similar situations:

I agree that this is most certainly a version conflict. Let's take it apart:

The root cause

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(Lorg/springframework/data/rest/core/mapping/RepositoryDetectionStrategy;)Lorg/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration;
```

means it is looking for a method with this signature:

```
public RepositoryRestConfiguration setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(RepositoryDetectionStrategy repositoryDetectionStrategy)
```

[Just as it is currently present in the current master](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.java#L565).

A quick look at the history of that class shows, that [the signature was changed not too long ago](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/commit/83899bb42af954cfe9ebe79622c36110a76d1061#diff-6f47bc1b6f277de59f8bb6ca2fa4802fR555).

So maybe something requires the new version but only gets the old one. The next line in the stacktrace shows what that is:

```
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestProperties.applyTo(RepositoryRestProperties.java:199) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
```

`spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE` seems to be the culprit.

I think there are two scenarios:

a) either `spring-cloud-starter-eureka` is dragging in an old dependency, causing a conflict.

b) or `spring-cloud-starter-eureka` is causing that path to execute, just triggering the problem that was present all the time.

So check your dependencies for the following:

1. Which version of Spring Data Rest do you have in the classpath?
2. Does that version change with vs without `spring-cloud-starter-eureka`? This should enable you to distinguish between scenario a) and b) above.

Try to force a new version of Spring Data Rest. Preferably by upgrading the top level dependencies already in your `pom.xml`. If the eureka thing changes the version a newer version of eureka might do the trick.

If it turns out that Spring Boot actually brings in the dependency, it is not compatible with (hard to believe, but shit happens), please file a bug with them.

Comment: Very helpful! Just like you mentioned in scenario a), the original `spring-data-rest-core` version is `2.6.0`, and after adding `spring-cloud-starter-parent : Camden.SR5` dependency, the `spring-data-rest-core` version change to `2.5.7` and cause the NoSuchMethod exception.

Comment: spring-cloud does not manage the version of spring-data-rest nor does it depend on spring-data-rest. If you use `mvn -X` you can see what is managing the version.